# How to edit flv comments?

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, file-properties, flv

On ubuntu when I right click a flv file and go to Properties > Audio/Video i see in the "General" section that is says "Comment:", but has no value. I need to add some text about the video there. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
flvtools2 -U comment:test file.flv
```